# Update and concatenate DataFrame with hierarchy levels in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, concatenation

I've a set of files (25 files) in a directory. I need to upload all files data into a single DataFrame, without loosing reference of the file name.

File structure (df):

```
date        Var1 Var2 Var3
1/01/2014   1    2    1
2/01/2014   12   20   10
...
31/01/2014  5    7    8
```

I'm doing the following

```
DATA_fin=pd.DataFrame()
m=0
for files in d:
    m=m+1
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    if m==1:
        DATA_fin=df

    else:
        gh=d[0:m]
        DATA_fin=pd.concat([DATA_fin, df], axis=1, keys=gh)
```

The above code does not work after the first iteration, as `Data_fin`and `df`have different levels.

I would like to get a final DataFrame as follows:

```
File 1                      File 2   
date        Var1 Var2 Var3  date        Var1 Var2 Var3
1/01/2014   1    2    1     1/01/2014   11   23   12
2/01/2014   12   20   10    2/01/2014   2    0    1 
...                         ... 
31/01/2014  5    7    8     31/01/2014  1    4    5
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your final DataFrame should really look like this. I suggest:

```
dfs = []
for file in d:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df['File'] = file
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Now each row knows where it comes from and the DataFrame can easily be rearranged.